# Load different CSS for different media-width

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm making a website, the design is responsive. But for the menu I'm choosing a simple toggle button, where the menu will reside when loaded on a mobile device. When the button will be hit, the menu will appear with a simple `<ul><li>` rendering bulleted list. But the thing is that, for the site, I did complex CSS for the menu; when I load the site in mobile device what should I do?

- Do I need to reset all the CSS properties done into the menu CSS, and then to do the mobile device-specific CSS into the media query?

I think that's not a viable idea.

Then, what should I do? A colleague of mine suggested me to load different CSS for different media-width, but **how**?

I want to avoid `@import` in CSS, as it decreases site speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can load different CSS for different viewport/media-width. Suppose, you made your site menu CSS into `menu.css`, and your mobile device's menu CSS into `mobile.css` then:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/menu.css' type='text/css' media='screen'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/mobile.css' type='text/css' media='screen and (max-width: 800px)'/>
```

The second stylesheet is specifically designed for mobile-device-friendly CSS, as you want, and the additional portion `and (max-width: 800px)` will load this stylesheet only on the specific viewport size.

So cheers!

Comment: To add to this, this is called CSS media queries, in case you want to Google more about the topic.

Comment: @MikeBrant Thanks. Actually I's working with CSS media queries, but was struggling with the menu CSS only. And with this way I solved my problem without viewport checker JS. :)

Comment: But this theory is disturbing when CSS minification is active. :(